# Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 2 issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices

**Update**

I changed the startup to :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Actio.Api.Handlers;
using Actio.Api.Repositories;
using Actio.Common.Auth;
using Actio.Common.Events;
using Actio.Common.Mongo;
using Actio.Common.RabbitMq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Actio.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddJwt(Configuration);
            services.AddRabbitMq(Configuration);
            services.AddMongoDB(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<IEventHandler<ActivityCreated>, ActivityCreatedHandler>();
            services.AddScoped<IActivityRepository, ActivityRepository>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            // app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDatabaseInitializer>().InitializeAsync();

            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDatabaseInitializer>().InitializeAsync();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I am having Error in **SubscribeToEvent**:
Cannot resolve scoped service

```
'Actio.Common.Events.IEventHandler`1[Actio.Common.Events.ActivityCreated]' from root provider.'
```

in my ServiceHost.cs.

**ServiceHost.cs**

```
using System;
using Actio.Common.Commands;
using Actio.Common.Events;
using Actio.Common.RabbitMq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using RawRabbit;

namespace Actio.Common.Services
{
    public class ServiceHost : IServiceHost
    {
        private readonly IWebHost _webHost;

        public ServiceHost(IWebHost webHost)
        {
            _webHost = webHost;
        }

        public void Run() => _webHost.Run();

        public static HostBuilder Create<TStartup>(string[] args) where TStartup : class
        {
            Console.Title = typeof(TStartup).Namespace;
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();
            var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseStartup<TStartup>();

            return new HostBuilder(webHostBuilder.Build());
        }

        public abstract class BuilderBase 
        {
            public abstract ServiceHost Build();
        }

        public class HostBuilder : BuilderBase
        {
            private readonly IWebHost _webHost;
            private IBusClient _bus;

            public HostBuilder(IWebHost webHost)
            {
                _webHost = webHost;
            }

            public BusBuilder UseRabbitMq()
            {
                _bus = (IBusClient)_webHost.Services.GetService(typeof(IBusClient));

                return new BusBuilder(_webHost, _bus);
            }

            public override ServiceHost Build()
            {
                return new ServiceHost(_webHost);
            }
        }

        public class BusBuilder : BuilderBase
        {
            private readonly IWebHost _webHost;
            private IBusClient _bus; 

            public BusBuilder(IWebHost webHost, IBusClient bus)
            {
                _webHost = webHost;
                _bus = bus;
            }

            public BusBuilder SubscribeToCommand<TCommand>() where TCommand : ICommand
            {
                var handler = (ICommandHandler<TCommand>)_webHost.Services
                    .GetService(typeof(ICommandHandler<TCommand>));
                _bus.WithCommandHandlerAsync(handler);

                return this;
            }

            public BusBuilder SubscribeToEvent<TEvent>() where TEvent : IEvent
            {
                var handler = (IEventHandler<TEvent>)_webHost.Services
                    .GetService(typeof(IEventHandler<TEvent>));
                _bus.WithEventHandlerAsync(handler);

                return this;
            }

            public override ServiceHost Build()
            {
                return new ServiceHost(_webHost);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I recently started learning Microservices with RabbitMQ. After much struggle I got a code sample but I am unable to run it as it is giving error `:"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Actio.Common.Mongo.IDatabaseInitializer' from root provider.'"`

I wish to understand this code so that I can have better understanding of Microservices.

**Code-Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Actio.Api.Handlers;
using Actio.Api.Repositories;
using Actio.Common.Auth;
using Actio.Common.Events;
using Actio.Common.Mongo;
using Actio.Common.RabbitMq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace Actio.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddJwt(Configuration);
            services.AddRabbitMq(Configuration);
            services.AddMongoDB(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<IEventHandler<ActivityCreated>, ActivityCreatedHandler>();
            services.AddScoped<IActivityRepository, ActivityRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
          //Giving Error in below line


app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IDatabaseInitializer>().InitializeAsync();
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseMvc();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help so that I can debug and l have better understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Have you set up IDatabaseInitializer in your DI?

Comment: yes.I have. 'using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Actio.Common.Mongo
{
    public interface IDatabaseInitializer
    {
        Task InitializeAsync();
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The below error is trying to tell you that you are registering `IDatabaseInitializer` as a **scoped service** but trying to access it outside the **scope**:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Actio.Common.Mongo.IDatabaseInitializer' from root provider.'"
```

Try to create a scope and then use the service like:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
{
    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IDatabaseInitializer>().InitializeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I changed but again some error in SubscribeToEvent method.Any help

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to disable scope validation.

So in file src\actio.common\services\servicehost.cs between lines 31-32 add the following:

```
.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => options.ValidateScopes = false)
```

Another alternative approach to solve the issue is changing from `services.AddScoped` to `services.AddSingleton` in program.cs, working with a singleton is gonna avoid all the scope validation as well.